# Calling Activity Method From Inside A Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to call a method in an activty from a Fragment screen.

I have a method called myMethod() which is in an activity called MyActivity;
I have a fragment called Screen1Fragment.

I would like to call MyActivity.myMethod() from inside the Screen1Fragment but I am not sure how to do this.

Previously the Screen1Fragment was an activity and so I was extending MyActivity so that I could directly call
myMethod().
But I have had to change the activity to a fragment for sliding tabs usage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `((YourActivityClass) getActivity).myMethod();`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Hi, when I try this I get an error saying cannot cast from FragmentActivity to MyActivity.
Does MyActivity have to extend FragmentActivity for me to be able to use this code.

Comment: Hi,
Sherif - your way was working yesterday but today it is causing my application to crash.
How can I attached the logcat to this post?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` in your fragment.

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
activity.myMethod();
```

if you are not sure if your fragment is attached to MyActivity then

```
 Activity activity = getActivity();
 if(activity instanceof MyActivity){
      MyActivity myactivity = (MyActivity) activity;
      myactivity.myMethod();
 }
```

Comment: Hi,
the first way gives me an error that cannot cast from FragmentActivity to MyActivity.
The second way does not give me an error but it is not loading the method on button click. Do I just place the code inside the button on click.

Comment: Then you should extend your Activity from FragmentActivity instead of Activity. (public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {...)

Comment: Hi, the first way was working great, but for some reason my application is now crashing when I try to use it.

Comment: Are you calling getActivity() after onAttach()? Are you sure it doesn't return null? Are you sure it is instance of MyActivity? Log these out, and you got your solution. Try using: Log.d("MyFragment", "getActivity(): "+getActivity()); before the casting

Comment: Thanks for getting back.
I am not sure how to use the log.d
This is the code I am running:
            TestActivity activity = (TestActivity) getActivity();
            activity.myMethod();
causes application to crash

Comment: Hi, if i put the method in my MainActivity and call the code
((MainActivity) getActivity()).myMethod();             
then it works

if I have the same method in my TestActivity and use the code
((TestActivity) getActivity()).myMethod();    
the application crashes

why is this?

Comment: I guess u attached your fragment to a MainActivity instead of TestActivity, so the instance returned by getActivity() is a MainActivity, and it cannot be casted to TestActivity.
And btw you should use logging. It help debugging very much, see the exceptions, log variables, etc... google it.

Comment: How do I attach my fragment to the Test Activity.
Or how can i call the method inside TestActivity please.

Comment: Same as you did in MainActivity, but use the code in your TestActivity.

Comment: I am not sure how I attached it,
My MainActivity has
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
  ActionBar.TabListener {

And TestActivity has
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

And GamesFragment
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Comment: Helpful... Thanks

Answer (score 28):

You should make your fragment totally independant of the activity you are attaching it to. The point of Fragments is that you can re-use them in different contexts with different activities. To achieve that and still being able to call methods from your Activity the following pattern in recommended in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

**In your fragment**:

- define a public interface with the method

  ```
  public interface MyFragmentCallback{
      public void theMethod();
  }
  ```
- define a field and get a cast reference:

  ```
  private MyFragmentCallback callback;
  public void onAttach(Activity activity){
      callback = (MyFragmentCallback) activity
      super.onAttach(activity);
  }
  ```

**In your Activity**

- implement `MyFragmentCallback` in the class definition.
- implement `theMethod()` in your activity (Eclipse will ask you to do so)

Then, from your fragment, you can call `callBack.theMethod()`

The difference between this and simply calling your method on getActivity() is that your fragment is not paired with this specific activity anymore. So you may re-use it with other activity for example one for phones and the other for tablets.

Comment: This is the correct way! Per google docs!

Comment: What to do in case of multiple fragments in single activity and we need callback for all fragments ?

Comment: @PareshBalar yes

Answer (score 0):

If the method is the static method of MainActivity, something like:

```
    public static void someMethod(){}
```

Then, it is pretty straightforward. Just call

```
   MainActivity.someMethod()
```

However, I guess what you really want is to access some function from the Activity class. Then you can use the following code in the Fragment view creater

```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState){

        container.getContext().someMethod();

   }
```

Comment: IMO this is bad practice. 1. container might be null, and getContext() returns Context, which u still have to check if MyActivity instance.
2. You don't want to communicate with Activity via static methods, since then it's not possible to have 2 instances of that Activity.

Comment: Good point. But I guess it is OK in this case. It seems the question owner wants some sliding tabs in the activity. We are pretty sure the activity is there. I am not suggesting to use a static method anyway. I am guessing what is the real question.